# IE8 Java Script error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp

The webpage works fine in Mozilla Firefox, but the same page when tried to access through IE8 throws the following error:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
>   msn OptimizedIE8;ENIN) Timestamp: Mon,
>   20 Jun 2011 05:20:13 UTC
>
> Message: Invalid argument. Line: 122
>   Char: 3 Code: 0

How to solve this??

```
function doBatchPrintPaySlipPentaho(form)
{

    var list = '';
    if(form.employeeIdList == null)
    {
        alert("No record for Batch Printing");
        return false;
    }
    if(form.employeeIdList.checked==false)
    {
        alert("Select one Employee");
        return false;
    }
    if(form.employeeIdList.checked == true)
    {
        list = "|" + form.employeeIdList.value;

    }
    else
    {
        var count=0;
        for(var i=0;i<form.employeeIdList.length;i++)
        {
            if(form.employeeIdList[i].checked == true)
            {
                count++;
                list += "|"+form.employeeIdList[i].value;
            }

        }
        if(count == 0)
        {
            alert("Select atleast one record");
            return false;
        }
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////
    var branchIdsTemp="";
    var employeeIdsTemp="";



    if(form.employeeIdList == null)
    {
        alert("No record for Batch Printing");
        return false;
    }
    if(form.employeeIdList.checked==false)
    {
        alert("Select one Employee");
        return false;
    }
    if(form.employeeIdList.checked == true)
    {
        list = "|" + form.employeeIdList.value;

    }
    else
    {
        var count=0;
        for(var i=0;i<form.employeeIdList.length;i++)
        {
            var xyz="";
            if(form.employeeIdList[i].checked == true)
            {
                count++;
                list += "|"+form.employeeIdList[i].value;
                xyz=form.employeeIdList[i].value.split("*");
                employeeIdsTemp=employeeIdsTemp+"&employee="+xyz[0];

            }

        }

        if(count == 0)
        {
            alert("Select atleast one record");
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(document.PaySlipGeneration.branch.value!='x')
    {
        branchIdsTemp="&branchId="+document.PaySlipGeneration.branch.value;
    }
    else
    {
        var allIds=document.PaySlipGeneration.allBranchIds.value.split("*");
        for(var z=0;z<allIds.length-1;z++)
        {
            branchIdsTemp=branchIdsTemp+"&branchId="+allIds[z];
        }
        //alert("branchIdsTemp : "+branchIdsTemp);
    }
    //return false;
    var tempFromDate="";
    var tempToDate="";
    var temp4=document.PaySlipGeneration.fromDate.value.split(".");
        tempFromDate=temp4[2].whiteSpaceTrimmer()+"-"+temp4[1].whiteSpaceTrimmer()+"-"+temp4[0].whiteSpaceTrimmer();
    var temp5=document.PaySlipGeneration.toDate.value.split(".");
        tempToDate=temp5[2].whiteSpaceTrimmer()+"-"+temp5[1].whiteSpaceTrimmer()+"-"+temp5[0].whiteSpaceTrimmer();

//window.open('batchSalarySlip?list='+list+'&from='+PaySlipGeneration.fromDate.value+'&to='+PaySlipGeneration.toDate.value+'&isFirstTime=true','','width=760,height=600,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes');

    MM_openBrWindow('http://reports.ofsy.net/pentaho/content/reporting/reportviewer/report.html?showParameters=false&output-target=pageable/pdf&solution=ofsyReports/bauto/payroll&path=&name=paySlipReport_bauto.prpt&locale=en_US#from='+tempFromDate.whiteSpaceTrimmer()+'&to='+tempToDate.whiteSpaceTrimmer()+branchIdsTemp+employeeIdsTemp+'&showParameters=false','&output-target=pageable/pdf','','width=1000,height=700,top=70,left=10');


//MM_openBrWindow('http://reports.ofsy.net/pentaho/content/reporting/reportviewer/report.html?showParameters=false&output-target=pageable/pdf&solution=ofsyReports/sta/payroll&path=&name=BankStatementReport_sta.prpt&locale=en_US#accNo='+accNo.whiteSpaceTrimmer()+'&from='+tempFromDate.whiteSpaceTrimmer()+'&to='+tempToDate.whiteSpaceTrimmer()+"&for_month="+for_month.whiteSpaceTrimmer()+branchIdsTemp+departmentIdsTemp+employeeIdsTemp+'&showParameters=false','&output-target=pageable/pdf','','width=1000,height=700,top=70,left=10');

}
```

Comment: You need to provide more context, such as an example of the code that generates the error.

Comment: can you post only that bit of the code, which generates the error? adding unnecessary code doesn't help our cause !

Comment: There aren't 122 lines in the code you've posted. So we've no idea what code produces the `invalid argument` error...

Comment: Yes, true, but that was the OP getting lucky :)

Comment: @Paul - happens a lot on my watch :)

Comment: @mplungjan: Rather than ranting in a mod flag, why not submit a [feature-request] on [meta]?

Comment: @Will, you mean [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89060/remove-2-vote-requirement-to-approve-suggested-edit), [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78799/why-multiple-approvers-for-proposed-edits), [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85846/why-do-edits-need-two-approvals-even-from-high-rep-users) - Sorry for the flag, but while it was not accepted, it was likely to be closed and downvoted just because the new user did not know how to format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your window open is for sure illegal

```
MM_openBrWindow('some long url',
'&output-target=pageable/pdf','','width=1000,height=700,top=70,left=10');
```

You need to find a way to remove either '&output-target=pageable/pdf' or the comma before it.

Also give the window a name, e.g.

```
MM_openBrWindow('some long url....&output-target=pageable/pdf',
'newWindow','width=1000,height=700,top=70,left=10');
```